# Return value only of last iteration

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to calculate the Greatest Common Divisor using a `while loop`. I am therefore looking for the greatest number (i.e. the last value of the loop). How do I get rid of the preceding numbers?

Example: 
The greatest common divisor of 84 and 18 is 6. However, my code gives me the numbers 2, 3, and 6. What do I need to change to get only the last number?

```
using System;

namespace CalculateGCD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            int i = 1;

          while (i <= Math.Min(a, b))
            {             
                i++;

                if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GCD:{0}", i);
                }             
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a variable called `max` then print the `max` out of the `while` loop like this:

```
int max = 0;

while (i <= Math.Min(a, b))
{
     i++;

     if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
     {
          max = i;
     }
}
Console.WriteLine("GCD:{0}", max);
```

Also if you are using C# 6 you could simplify your `Console.WriteLine` by using string interpolation like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"GCD:{max}");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution which will calculate GCD

```
static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
}
```

and you can use it like below

```
using System;

namespace CalculateGCD
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine(GCD(a,b));
        }

        static int GCD(int a, int b) 
        {
           return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From reading the question, I'm assuming that the OP is a beginner at java. Maybe it's not useful to show examples containing ternary operators and recursion without explaining it a bit further. That just results in copying code.

Comment: ok, sure no problem, I have just tried to show the simplest way :) BTW its not a Java program

Comment: I'm a beginner at C# and the homework I'm dealing with asks me to find GCD using loops. However, I appreciate your solution.

Comment: @MostafizurRahman no problem man, it was just a sidenote : ) and i meant c# of course, silly me^^

Answer (score 1):

```
int gcd;
while (i <= Math.Min(a, b))
{             
    i++;
    if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
    {
        gcd=i;
    }             
}
Console.WriteLine("GCD:{0}",gcd);
```

Save greatest common divisor in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the loop, insted of going from 1 to the Min between `a` and `b`, search from the Min to 1.

```
int i = Math.Min(a, b);
while (i > 0)
{
    i--;

    if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GCD:{0}", i);
        break;
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply reverse the enumeration sequence will do

```
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i = Math.Min(a ,b);
while (i > 1)
{
  if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("GCD:{0}", i);
      break;//greatest will be the first
  }
  i--;
 }
```